# Ignore scss while testing svelte components with Jest

Tags: javascript, css, unit-testing, jestjs, svelte

**Problem:** I want to test svelte components  with jest but unable to do so since I'm unable to ignore the scss style mentioned inside the component. Is there a way to bypass the scss. My approach so far is as follows:-

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.svelte$': 'svelte-jester',
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'svelte'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^.*\\.scss$": "SCSSStub.js"
    }
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
}
```

**SCSSStub.js**

```
module.exports = {};
```

Apart from this approach, I tried identity-obj-proxy as well as adding

```
moduleNameMapper: { '^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'babel-jest',},
```

to jest.config.js. None of them worked.

Comment: are you getting any error with this or does it simply not work? If there's an error, could you share the error stacktrace as well?

Comment: When I configured the jest as mentioned & executed the test, I would keep getting parse error  since the test can't bypass the scss in my svelte file. When I removed the scss from the svelte file, the tests would execute as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the way you have configured `moduleNameMapper`. The regex would look for something like `filename\.scss`

There is an extra forward slash due to which the forward slash would be escaped instead of the dot resulting in the mocking happening only if there is a forward slash before the extension.

Change your regex to `^.+\.(css|less|scss)$` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Can you possibly share your src and test file and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `svelte-jester` run the preprocesser. According to [their README](https://github.com/mihar-22/svelte-jester#preprocess):

#### jest.config.js

```
// replace this line
'^.+\\.svelte$': 'svelte-jester',
// with this one
'^.+\\.svelte$': ['svelte-jester', {preprocess: true}],
```

Then you will likely run into the issue of not having a `svelte.config.js` file, which `svelte-jester` expects you to have if you are running the preprocessor. The [discussion for that is here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1101) and a [solution to it is here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/397). For good measure, here is my solution:

#### svelte.config.js

```
import autoPreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

const preprocessOptions = {
  scss: {
    // your scss preprocess options here
  }
};

const preprocess = autoPreprocess(preprocessOptions);

export {
  preprocess,
  preprocessOptions
};
```

#### rollup.config.js

```
// ... snip
import {preprocess} from './svelte.config';
// ... snip
    svelte({
      preprocess,
      // ... other svelte options
    }),
// ... snip
```

EDIT:
If you get errors related to native modules, then the simplest solution is to switch `svelte.config.js` and `rollup.config.js` to commonjs syntax. I was seeing that only in a particular Docker build and not on my local machine, so hopefully the above is generally correct.